# rails/heroku route error /stylesheets/all.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm new to rails and very new to Heroku, but I've recently hosted my app up on Heroku and am getting the following error in my log:

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/all.css" for ...
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/all.css"):
```

I stumbled across this forum (http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38540) where someone was able to fix a similar problem by setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in their `config/environments/prodcution.rb`, but this did not work for me. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? To clarify, I only get this error in production, not in dev. Thanks.

Also, rather interesting is that I am actually able to access `/stylesheets/styles.css` with no problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a blank `all.css` file?

Comment: Benjamin, all.css is a dynamically created stylesheet that includes every stylesheet in your public/stylesheets folder and is created at runtime. Thus it is vital for most Rails 3+ users to have that file found.